# Views not work in D6 after upgrading php version to 5.4

Tags: 6, views, upgrading

After upgrading php version to 5.4 in drupal version 6, views not work and show fields as `Broken/missing handler:`

you can see the screenshot of it .
where is problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you aware that [Drupal recommends PHP 5.2 for Drupal 6](https://drupal.org/requirements)? Also - we can't really know what's wrong from a screenshot. Watchdog and error.log are the places you have to investigate. Share relevant parts. Last but not least, is it Views 2 or Views 3?

Comment: @Mołot yes I know. I didnt create this site, my company is supporter of it ,  I dont see any error only E_STRICT  warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in /sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 906

Comment: So you have a file and line number :) File a bugreport to views, or open that file and try to fix it yourself (and then file a bugreport + patch to views). And if problem will persist after that, ask again (or edit this question). Also, ask your sysadmin to log all warnings (or turn it on yourself) on your dev copy.

Comment: @Mołot I search for this warning, It is not reason of this problem, we have another site in this server, with the same views module, I hide warning by bypass them , that work correctly  , I think the reason is in the another place

Comment: PHP really changes between versions much like jQuery, and Views is really a giant wrapper around a lot of other modules, and all it takes is one to break and bring it down, so I would look and see what other modules might be failing that hook into it. Above, for example, I can see you are using the (usually wonderful) Flag module so you will need to check it as well.  That coupled with the fact that you do appear to be using Views 2 (based upon the line number of your error [906]) suggests you will have quite the uphill challenge here.  Good luck!